# How do I exclude when all lines matches

Tags: sql, teradata, matching

I’m looking to exclude all rows when there is matching edit_codes to line_nbr.

Teradata SQL query:

```
Select d.*
From decision_table d
LEFT OUTER JOIN edit_codes e ON 
d.unique_key=e.unique_key
WHERE e.source_edit like (‘hp%’)
AND d.line_nbr <>SUBSTR(e.edit_line_nbr, 
3,2)
***OR I wrote it as “AND d.line_number = 
SUBSTR(e.edit_line_nbr,3,2)
```

Q1: Even though, row 2 and 3 (EDIT_CODES TO LINE_NBR) don’t match, however, since row 1 and 4 does I want to exclude. How do I write it to capture if line_nbr matches any edit_codes on any row?

```
row#    EDIT_CODES  LINE_NBR
1       HP01        01
2       HP02        01
3       HP01        02
4       HP02        02
```

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are trying to describe.  What is a line?  Is that a "row" in a table?  What does "match on all lines" mean?  How is "vice versa" being used?

Comment: I'm trying to match the edit_codes to the line_nbr but in the first table row 2 and 3 are vice versa matches and line 1 and 4 are perfect matches, I want to capture even when the matches are vice versa. Hopefully I'm making better sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: I made additional edits to try and simplify my questions.

Comment: Just trying to clarify your rules am I correct in my understanding... Rule 1) If the last 2 characters of EDIT_CODES match the LINE_NBR for the same record then do not select 2) if line_NBR matches the last two characters of EDIT_CODES on any record then exclude.... therefor from the first query nothing would be selected? and from the second query all except row 5 would be selected?

Comment: The first query would either exclude or include based on the line matching and not matching, but I want to be able to capture the lines when it's vice versa, meaning row 2 and 3 aren't matching but it would match if I found a match on the other row.                          Disregard my second question.

Comment: I thought I understood but then I read the question again and realized I didn’t. Please clarify your question with input data, expected output and a clear explanation of the logic to get the expected result.